# How to configure Pivotal Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, greenplum, hawq

We are working on a Greenplum with HAWQ installed. I would like to run a hadoop-streaming job. However, it seems that hadoop is not configured or started. How can i start mapred to make sure that i can use hadoop-streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command to get word count:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-input <inputDir> \
-output <outputDir> \
-mapper /bin/cat \
-reducer /bin/wc
```

If that gives you correct word count then its working else check the error that's spit out by running this command

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that cluster is started and is working. To make it go to the Pivotal Command Center (usually the link is like this: `https://<admin_node>:5443/` ) and see the cluster status or ask your administrator to do so.

Next, make sure that you have the PHD client libraries installed on the machine you are trying to start your job. Run "rpm -qa | grep phd"

Next, if the cluster is running and libraries are installed, you can run the streaming job like this:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/gphd/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -mapper /bin/cat -reducer /bin/wc -input /example.txt -output /testout
```

/example.txt file should exist on HDFS

Answer (score -1):

I do it long back, Greenplum/Pivotal Hadoop

--1. For Instatllation
icm_client deploy  
ex. - icm_client deploy HIVE

--2. For status
HDFS
Service hadoop-namenode status
Service hadoop-datanode status
Service hadoop-secondarynamenode status
MapRed
Service hadoop-jobtracker status
Service hadoop-tasktracker status
Hive
service hive-server status
service hive-metastore status

--3. For start/stop/restart
service hive-server start
service hive-server stop
service hive-server restart

Note: You will find all this command and details in installation guide, may be available online somewhere hadoop installation guide

Thanks,